# IntelXDK native bridge not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, intel-xdk

I am trying to create an android application using IntelXDK and when it runs on a simulator it works fine, but when I try and run it on a physical device none of the native features work.

I have included this code in my head tag:

```
    <script src="intelxdk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I am trying to use this (which is the code off of their website: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493021) in the body

```
    intel.xdk.device.launchExternal('http://www.google.com');
```

However nothing happens when the link is clicked

I have included the device plugin as shown below:
[image: device plugin]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this through App Preview or a built app?  Did you make sure you included the intel xdk device plugin?

Comment: It is through a built app, I have included the device plugin and updated my question to show it

Comment: Aaaaah I selected 'device' under Cordova Plugins instead of intel xdk!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using intel.xdk plugins but you show that you've selected the standard Cordova plugins.  The intel.xdk plugins are under "Featured & Custom Cordova Plugins".  It's a bit confusing because some of them share the same name (like "device").